# Importing commit from Bitbucket to Existing Gitlab repo

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitlab

I am working on this large project and my source code is being stored on Gitlab.

I gave the code to another person and they have done some major work to it and they store it on Bitbucket.

Now I want to take the person's code and add it to my existing Gitlab repo (as a new commit). How can I do that?

I am using Windows.

Thanks

Edit: You have unmeged paths.
[image]

Comment: I think you have to start getting your hands dirty by cherry-picking. So, add a new remote to the bitbucket repo, fetch and then start cherry-picking to your branches (or merge/rebase, whatever you think makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to this is by using the Git bash that msysgit provides.

You can setup multiple origins and you can merge their branches with your current working tree. I assume the other person made only changes his master branch.

**First**
setup the other repository as another remote:
`git remote add bitb "https://bitbucket......."`

**Then**
fetch the changes from this remote
`git fetch bitb master`

**And now you have to decide**

**a) Usually (the simple, git-way of doing things)** you merge the other branch into your master branch
`git merge bitb/master`

This way you preserve all his commits and merge them with your changes in `master`. Your repositories will also stay compatible together for future collaboration.

**b) I don't think you really want to squash all his changes into one single commit and merge this** in which case you **lose** all his notes and simple changes and the compatibility of your repositories.

If you really wanted to do so you could switch to his branch (`git checkout bitb/master`) and use `git rebase -i master` to squash all his commits since he diverged from master into one single commit, switch back to master (`git checkout master` and merge the single commit to your master (`git merge bitb/master`)

**Think about the Keep-it-simple principle and select the first option.**

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I followed your steps and I got "You have unmerged paths" please see my edit in original post.....what should i do?

Comment: Hi! Unmerged paths means that there are some files (listed in the section "Both added") that you changed but as well the other person changed. git's magic in honor - but it can't decide how to merge/how to combine the changes correctly. You need to open the files and see what parts of the code you both (simultanously) changed and how to arrange this. Git will put ">>>>" markers inside the files. The obj/* files that are automatically created and you don't care about, can be deleted manually. Then run `git add .` and `git commit` to finish the merge.

Comment: Wow, I literally have hundreds of files (note the picture in question was just a demo). Is there a quick way to "Except ALL the other person's changes" automatically?

Comment: Do you mean accept? Yes there is, you can run `git merge --abort` to undo the changes git already did and then use `git merge -X theirs bitb/master`

Comment: But keep in mind that this will entirely discard your changes, if the other person changed the same part as well.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Yes, sorry "ACCEPT" was what i meant to say. And yes, I don't care about my changes. All I care is to get the other person changes. Will "git merge --abort" able to deal with files added or deleted by the other person? The other person may have added some files or deleted some old files. I just want my tree to have the exactly the same copy as the other person's tree if you know what i mean.

Comment: Have you seen my other answer? I accidentally posted it as an answer. This might be the easiest way to achieve what you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ask myself if you even want to merge the changes or just get an exact copy of what the other person has done. You might also `git reset --hard bitb/master` and your working tree will look perfectly the same as at the other person's computer. You will however lose commits you made since you gave the other person the code...

Comment: what command do i have to run before running the command in this post? i just tried something and it didn't work. Can you give me a complete step by step again giving that I just want an exact copy of the other person has done. thank you so much for helping.

Comment: `git remote add bitb "https://bitbucket........" ; git fetch bitb master ; git reset --hard bitb/master`

Comment: i did that and my repo is not updated??? am i missing a git commit/add/push or something?

Comment: head is now pointing to the other person's commit....but my repo doesn't get updated with their stuff

Comment: Try `git checkout HEAD -- .` What's the output?

Comment: git checkout head -- gives:


Note: checking out 'head'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 77ed791... inital released for copy app




like i said, head is now pointing to the other person's

Comment: Then you should basically have the changes in your working directory... Else try `git checkout bitb/master`