# Git - how to update my repo with new code from other developer

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have been working on a very large project.
I have my project on Gitlab called ProjectXYZ and there has been several commits in the past by me.

I recently gave my code to a third person who did some changes **(this could be adding, deleting, modifying files)**.

While I gave the code to that third person, I did not make any changes on my side. So, if anything is changes it is on that third person.

The person just recently handed me back the full code with their modification in a .ZIP folder.

I extracted the ZIP folder and launched the solution file and confirm that things are working with the new code from that person.

Now, I want to push this new code to my existing ProjectXYZ on Gitlab. I also want to preserver all the previous commits.

The following steps are what I think I will going to do so please let me know if this will work.

1) I will go into my existing ProjectXYZ directory on my local PC and delete everything there except the **.git** folder (to preserve the git).

2) I then copy everything from the folder the other person has sent me and paste it into my existing ProjectXYZ directory on my local PC.

3) I will do a git add* -> git commit -> git push -> to update my git repo.

Note: Because I did not make any changes on my side after I gave the code to that third person so there is no worry for me of losing any code changes by me.

Please let me know if that a correct way of doing. I understand that there maybe other way to do, but believe me, I have tried and failed like this one [My other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620379/importing-commit-from-bitbucket-to-existing-gitlab-repo/43644380?noredirect=1#comment74581756_43644380)

Thank you

Comment: If your working tree will be standing on the revision from the point where the developer started working, it sounds correct.... although, when committing, make sure to set the --author so that you know who to blame if something is not correct.

Comment: @ Edmundo will I lose any histories/ track changes?

Comment: As long as you don't delete your .git directory, you won't lose anything from the history of the project.

Comment: ... which makes me think: make sure there's no .git stuff inside the zip that could mess up your repo.

Comment: yes, there is no git stuff on the zip folder. i already checked that,

Comment: @Edmundo What is your thought on the answer giving by Ivan Rodrigues? Which method would you recommended?

Comment: i don't see the need for a rebase... but that's my personal taste. You can start the "changes" branch, as I said, from the point where the other developer started working (you might have moved master forward so starting right from master could be wrong, it depends) and then feel free to do as you please with the changes (merge, rebase, whatever suits your personal taste).

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this steps:

1. git checkout -b changes (where changes are all changes did by third person)
2. paste all files from .zip in this branch
3. execute git add, commit and push like you said
4. do a rebase: git rebase master
5. Return to master with git checkout master

Why do this ?

When you use rebase instead merge you mantain clean your log beyond of you preserve the changes isolated in another branch.

Comment: @ Ivan How do I do  2) paste all files from .zip in this branch?

Comment: Extract the content of .zip to your recently created branch named changes

Comment: when I do git checkout -b changes -> git is creating a new branch called changes but I won't be able to see this folder on my local directory so how do it paste stuff into there?

Comment: Use git branch, this command will list all branches and you'll see that changes is your current branch

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to paste the stuff in the .zip folder into the 'changes' branch. Do I have to go to the master directory and delete everything there and paste the stuff from the .zip into this folder and commit while i am on the 'changes' branch?

Comment: In the new branch you can delete all files and then paste files from .zip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145229/discussion-between-ivan-rodrigues-and-cb4).

Answer (score 0):

@Ivan Rodrigues

I started with your suggestion and eventually I found the solution as follow. This method is:

i) create a "dev" branch

ii) make and commit any changes to this dev branch (you don't have to "push" if you don't want git to show a dev branch on the project tree)

iii) finally merge this to master

Here are the steps that works for me:

1.git checkout -b BranchX

2.do your dev work ... or make any changed to files/folder/directory as needed

3.git add * (to add all changes)

4.git commit -m "my message"

5.git push origin BranchX (you don't need to do this and it stills work)

6.git rebase master

7.git checkout master

8.git merge BranchX

9.git push origin master

Now, Master branch will have all the latest stuff.

Again, thank you so much for the help everyone.

Comment: can someone please confirm if the method I described here a proper way to do? I just don't want to have any problem later on. Thanks